# Why can't I install a PPA?

Tags: 11.10, ppa

Hello I'm trying to install a PPA,but the software center doesn't read it. I try for hardware sensors idicator and for handbrake and they don't appear in the all software tab so I can install them. Plus my software center is acting all weird like if it was buggy, I liked the old one better,simple.

I did what Luis Alvarado told me to do in the terminal and nothing. I copy and past it `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:stebbins/handbrake-snapshots` and then I updated with `sudo apt-get update` and still nothing for handbrake it doesn't show up in the software center.

- Ok everyone I got to install handbrake it works for some reason I had to restart my computer and there it was. Thanks for the help.
- Ok everyone I got to install the hardware sensors indicator. The problem was I forgot to install the lm-sensors package. I also install the sensor indicator through sypnaptic package manager. I follow this guy thanks for the help. http://reformedmusings.wordpress.com/2011/10/15/panel-hardware-sensors-in-ubuntu-unity-for-oneiric-11-10/

Comment: Most likely the PPAs don't have packages for 11.10 yet. Which PPAs are you trying to use?

Comment: Handbrake and Hardware sensors indicator. I did what Luis Alvarado told me to do in the terminal and nothing. I copy and past it sudo add-apt-repository ppa:stebbins/handbrake-snapshots and then I updated with sudo apt-get update and still nothing for handbrake it doesn't show up in the software center.

Answer (score 4):

Did you try, for example, assuming you want the PPA snapshot version of handbrake.

1. Google for "ppa handbreak". In the second link of launchpad it says snapshot.
2. On the snapshot handbreak launchpad page: https://launchpad.net/~stebbins/+archive/handbrake-snapshots copy the ppa line: **ppa:stebbins/handbrake-snapshots**

In my case I go to the console/terminal and type there:
`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:stebbins/handbrake-snapshots`

Then I wait for the ppa to merge with the source.list and then do an update. Either `sudo aptitude update` or `sudo apt-get update`.

Now IF the ppa has the package for the 11.10 version, you should see it. If not you need to wait until it appears in the PPA. In this case the PPA was updated about 14 hours ago with the 11.10 version for it BUT remember, this is a snapshot.

Then just go to synaptic, software center, aptitude, apt-cache or whichever you want and you should see the new version there saying hello.