# How do I download and install Handbrake?

Tags: command-line, software-installation, downloads

I'm new at Ubuntu so I don't know very well how to use the terminal in order to download and install programs that aren't in the software center. I've tried without success downloading and installing Handbrake.

Could anybody help me, guiding me through the downloading and installation of Handbrake?

Comment: maybe this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/65819/why-cant-i-install-a-ppa

Comment: Please excuse my complete lack of understanding on how Ubuntu works, but how do you "run" said programme? Is it alt+F2 and then enter "sudo add-apt-repository ppa:stebbins/handbrake-releases"? What should happen after this? Really can't get my head around Ubuntu at all!

Comment: Note that the accepted answer is now outdated. Handbrake is in the main repositories under "Universe and no PPA is required". See the answer below for full details.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

There are two official HandBrake PPAs, `ppa:stebbins/handbrake-releases` and `ppa:stebbins/handbrake-git-snapshots`.

The former contains stable releases, which are updated about once a year. These releases tend to be rather out-dated when their end-of-life is approaching. The current stable version (0.9.8) was released on 2012-07-18.

The latter contains nightly builds, which are updated daily (or nightly, as it were). These are of course less stable, and undocumented to boot, but they are good software nonetheless. Additionally, as the stable release ages, the developers tend to start recommending users to try the nightly builds instead.

To add one of these to your sources, simply run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:stebbins/handbrake-releases
```

or

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:stebbins/handbrake-git-snapshots
```

depending on which you want. To install HandBrake with the GUI, run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install handbrake
```

Alternatively, if you would prefer the CLI (command-line interface) over the GUI, replace the last line with:

```
sudo apt-get install handbrake-cli
```

Comment: The `-releases` PPA doesn't seem to offer amd64 packages. Despite appearing in Launchpad's [list of Quantal packages](https://launchpad.net/~stebbins/+archive/handbrake-releases/+packages?field.name_filter=&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=quantal), Synaptic only shows the `i386` packages, which won't install. Weird.

Comment: That is quite the comprehensive and concise answer, my most sincere regards to you sir :D

Comment: If you see only `mkv` file format option and missing `mp4` then install `handbrake` like this [https://askubuntu.com/a/473520](https://askubuntu.com/a/473520)

Answer (score 9):

The [handbrake ppa](https://launchpad.net/~stebbins/+archive/handbrake-releases) has been updated with the latest version of handbrake.

**PPA**

To install copy/paste the next lines of codes one by one in your gnome-terminal

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:stebbins/handbrake-releases
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install handbrake-cli handbrake-gtk
```

**Currently supports**: 
Raring (13.04), Quantal (12.10), Precise (12.04), Oneiric (11.10), Natty (11.04), Maverick (10.10), Lucid (10.04), Karmic (9.10).

**Note**: You can still install the latest version of handbrake on Ubuntu 13.10, by manually downloading the appropriate `.deb` files:

- [handbrake-cli_0.9.9ppa1~quantal1_amd64.deb](http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-releases/ubuntu/pool/main/h/handbrake/handbrake-cli_0.9.9ppa1~quantal1_amd64.deb)
- [handbrake-gtk_0.9.9ppa1~quantal1_amd64.deb](http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-releases/ubuntu/pool/main/h/handbrake/handbrake-gtk_0.9.9ppa1~quantal1_amd64.deb)

I managed to install them on my Ubuntu 13.10 amd64 without issues

---

**From source**

If you want to compile it from source, here is what worked for me:

first install dependencies.

```
sudo apt-get install bzr subversion yasm build-essential \
autoconf libtool zlib1g-dev libbz2-dev libfribidi-dev \
intltool libglib2.0-dev libdbus-glib-1-dev libgtk2.0-dev \
libgudev-1.0-dev libwebkit-dev libnotify-dev \
libgstreamer0.10-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev
```

Then download and compile

```
bzr branch lp:handbrake
cd handbrake
./configure
cd ./build
sudo make
sudo make install
```

**Source**:

- [How to compile HandBrake from source - EuroBytes](http://www.eurobytes.nl/tutorials/handbrake-from-source)

Answer (score 3):

HandBrake is available in the Ubuntu Software Center, search for it

[image]

If you have not made any changes to your Software Sources, you should be directed to an install page instead of what is in the above image. To add the "universe" source to your sources, go to Edit>Software Sources and check under the tab Ubuntu Software the "Community-maintained free and open-source software (universe)" and close.

[image]

Or just click the button to use that source.

Answer (score 1):

Handbrake doesn't have any ppa support in 12.04.  If you've tried adding the PPA's and still get the error, this solution resolved the problem for me

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/stebbins-handbrake-*
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-add-repository ppa:stebbins/handbrake-snapshots
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install handbrake-gtk handbrake-cli
```

You need to do the update process twice, first time to remove the invalid ppas from the hit list, and the second time adds the correct PPA.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but `sudo rm stebbins-handbrake-* /etc/apt/source.list.d/` seems like wrong syntax. If your intention is to remove files that match `stebbins-handbrake-*` and are located in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`, it will *not* do that. (`sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/stebbins-handbrake-*` will.)

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. I had already tried to install Handbrake under 13.10 but it wasn't working. I removed the existing release source, added the snapshots and then installed handbrake without issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add these packages to compile on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS:

```
sudo apt-get install libass-dev libtheora-dev libvorbis-dev libsamplerate-dev
```

The binary is then in `build/gtk/src` (ghb), and you can run it directly without using `makeinstall`.

Answer (score 0):

None of the previous solutions worked for me with Ubuntu 13.10.  The one involving "bzr" fell over with:

```
../libhb/decssasub.c:30:21: fatal error: ass/ass.h: No such file or directory
 #include <ass/ass.h>
                 ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [libhb/decssasub.o] Error 1
```

However I managed to get it working by downloading directly and installing using dpkg.
(taken from http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/10/install-handbrake-in-ubuntu-13-10-saucy/)

For 32-bit:

```
wget https://launchpad.net/~stebbins/+archive/handbrake-releases/+files/handbrakegtk_0.9.9ppa1~raring1_i386.deb
```

For 64-bit:

```
wget https://launchpad.net/~stebbins/+archive/handbrake-releases/+files/handbrakegtk_0.9.9ppa1~raring1_amd64.deb
```

Then install
    sudo dpkg -i handbrake-gtk_0.9.9ppa1~raring1_*.deb

and fix dependencies
   sudo apt-get -f install

Please tell me in the comments if you know what library I'm missing for the "bzr" option to work.  I've got a fairly new Ubuntu install.

Cheers,
  Stuart.