# Cannot install Handbrake in 64-bit Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: package-management, repository, synaptic, handbrake

When I go into Synaptic and try to install the handbrake-gtk, after it gives me the list of all the other packages it has to install, I get this message:

> The following packages have unresolved dependencies. Make sure that
>   all required repositories are added and enabled in the 'Repositories'
>   option under 'Settings'
>
> handbrake-gtk:i386:  Depends: libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 but it is not going
>   to be installed

I tried installing in the terminal but that wouldn't work either, I think for the same reason.

Now using the pages http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/webkit_team?dist=precise and http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/webkit_team/precise/main/base/libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 and the terminal I supposedly added and install the libwebkitgtk-1.0.0 package, but whenever I go back into Synaptic and try to install Handbrake I still get the same error message.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at [This](http://askubuntu.com/questions/107915/how-do-i-download-and-install-handbrake)

Comment: No sorry, still not working. Compiling from source was working right up until `sudo make` when, after about 5 minutes of code just streaming past me in the terminal, I got an error message. I tried to go on to `sudo make install` but I just got a similar error message.

Comment: Try installing from [USC](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/handbrake-gtk/)

Comment: Hmmm, I suspect that you have the 64bit version of libwebkit installed but handbrake wants the 32bit version. Maybe try to manually install libwebkitgtk-1.0-0:i386. (In synaptic or using apt-get.)

Comment: Mitch - Nope, I'm getting package not found

Comment: Bene - Synaptic can't find it, and apt-get says it needs other packages because they're dependencies. When I try to install those too, through apt-get, it just says they're unavailable.

Comment: I had this working on 10.04 x64, but same problem on Xubuntu 12.10 64bit, can anyone else suggest a solution? Thanks in advance, themobmob

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I did was the following:

Since using any of the 2 PPAs in: [https://launchpad.net/~stebbins](https://launchpad.net/%7Estebbins) was actually not working for 64 bit systems, I just went and downloaded the package. In my case I did the following:

1. Used the Handbrake Snapshot PPA found [here](https://launchpad.net/%7Estebbins/+archive/handbrake-snapshots)
2. Click on **View Package Details**

   [image]
3. Select the Ubuntu version you are using, then click on **Filter**

   [image]
4. Click on the most updated Package available there. In this case there is only one. It should expand to show everything related to that package.

   [image]
5. Go down until you get to where all packages for each Architecture are shown. Download the ones that are for your version. In this case, the ones that say amd64 are for 64 Bit systems.

   [image]
6. After downloading both (The CLI and GUI Versions), simply double click them. Software Center will take care of the rest.

The end result should be something like this:

[image]

This is what I did on 12.04, 12.10 and even on 13.04 using the 12.10 package. All cases with 64 Bit PCs.

Comment: @schtocker the only thing am sorry about is that the borders of the images are the same as the background color of the post. In my monitor it looks kind of strange to see Text, then the image, then Text and so on.