# How to transfer a DVD to my hard drive

Tags: dvd, cd-ripping, disk-ripping

I have several DVD I want to transfer to my Hard drive. I want to have the DVD menu and such. Not only the movie. I was sure that ripping the movie will do the trick but it didn't work. What can I do then?

I tried dvd::rip and acidrip. Both aren't that clear to operate.

Comment: KDEs KIO has an IO slave called videodvd. In any KDE program you can enter videodvd:/ as URL and see the unencrypted DVD files. If you copy all of them to a folder, you can use mplayer or vlc to play that folder as a DVD (not the individual files - you must tell the player that the folder is the DVD-device - read mplayer documentation to find out how). Another option is to use k9copy, a clone of the famous DVDshrink. Both solutions need libdvdcss installed. Beware, that it might be illegal in your country to rip DVDs.

Comment: you also may want to have a look at [handbrake](http://askubuntu.com/questions/107915/how-do-i-download-and-install-handbrake).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the [dd](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dd) command.  You can save the disc as ISO, and then you can mount and play.  just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sr0 of=~/<file_name>.iso
```

Comment: I guess I'll have to replace ``/dev/sr0`` with ``/dev/dvd``

Answer (score 4):

You can use GNU-ddrescue (https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/manual/ddrescue_manual.html) for ripping. It is better than `dd`, because it retries failed reads and skips unreadable parts (if disk is scratched).

Open a Terminal (with for example <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and install GNU ddrescue:

```
  sudo apt-get install gddrescue
```

than ripp disk:

```
  ddrescue -b 2048 -d -r 2 -v /dev/sr0 <Destination>.iso <Destination>.log
```

Stop ripping with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, because reading of scratched DVDs may take long. You can resume ripping with calling  same command again.

If DVD is encrypted you have to install `libdvdcss` ([How can I play encrypted DVD movies?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/500/how-can-i-play-encrypted-dvd-movies)) and open DVD with a movie player like vlc before ripping (GNU ddrescue will not decrypt DVD).

Answer (score 2):

if your dvd contains movie, you can use **VLC media player**

> open VLC media player >> Media >> Convert / Save or `Ctrl+R`

then select Disk tab, browse disk device and if you dont know where is the DVD is then you can just right click on the DVD on your left pane `Files` and choose `Properties` you will see the DVD **location** like `/media/username/DVDname`.

then press `convert/save` button, wait and dont close your VLC until the **streaming** process is done.

more: https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/2696/how-to-rip-dvds-with-vlc/

Comment: This is not the best answer to the actual question which specifies keeping the menu.  However, this is my personal favorite answer - the one that I was really hoping for.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Currently doing this...

If your DVDs are **encrypted** and the *dd* command isn't working, you first need to install *libdvdread4*. Then you will able to use the *dd* command as instructed [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/344509/299325).

`sudo apt-get install libdvd-pkg`
`sudo dpkg-reconfigure libdvd-pkg`
 `sudo dd if=/dev/sr0 of=~/Desktop/<file_name>.iso`